# Convert ExtJs Web Application into Desktop Application

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, extjs, sencha-architect

I'm creating a web application through ExtJs (Sencha Architect) and now I want to convert it into desktop application too!

I did create a runnable .exe for windows for My application through SDP (Sencha Package Manager) old version but it is trial version so I'm not able to run it any more! And Sencha also discontinues SDP for sale anymore.

I want to convert My web application into desktop runnable application for multiple platforms (i.e. Windows, Mac, Linux etc)

So I'm confuse to change My web application into desktop runnable application?

Please help me, is there any solution for solving this problem.

Any kind of solution could be useful for Me, so please send Me any useful suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit)! It makes your web app like a native one, it runs on mac, windows and linux.

There is also [appjs](http://appjs.com) but it is not maintained anymore.

Comment: Thanks a lot!

I'm not able to make an executable file for My Application through Node Web-Kit

Comment: Thanks Dear, I did it now through Node WebKit

Answer (score 0):

You can use Adobe AIR to do the same. It provides Platform independent support.

Please take a look at http://layersmagazine.com/adobe-air-turns-web-developers-into-desktop-developers.html

Note that your app should still be up and running in your Web server. !